# Reference to object pointed by list iterator not working

Tags: c++, reference

I have a container class `Query_List` :

```
template <typename Data>
class query_list
{
private:
    std::mutex mx_lock;

    // Underlaying container for fast read, write and acces
    std::list<Data> m_DataArray;

    // Index table used for fast acces over the container
    std::map<uint32_t, typename std::list<Data>::iterator> m_IndexTable;
public:
    query_list() { }

    void Push_Back(const uint32_t& ID, const Data& Val)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> _l(mx_lock);

        // Add data to the container
        m_DataArray.push_back(Val);

        // Get iterator to the new alocated data
        auto iter = m_DataArray.end();
        --iter;

        // Asociate ID with the index in the list
        m_IndexTable[ID] = iter;
    }

    bool AtID(const uint32_t& ID, Data &To_Get)
    {
        if (!Exists(ID))
            return false;

        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> _l(mx_lock);

        To_Get = *m_IndexTable[ID];
        return true;
    }

    void Remove(const uint32_t& ID)
    {
        // Data has already been freed!
        if (!Exists(ID)) return;

        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> _l(mx_lock);

        m_DataArray.erase(m_IndexTable[ID]);
        m_IndexTable[ID] = m_DataArray.end();
    }

    bool Exists(const uint32_t& ID)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> _l(mx_lock);

        if (m_IndexTable.find(ID) == m_IndexTable.end())
            return false;

        if (m_IndexTable[ID] == m_DataArray.end())
            return false;

        return true;
    }
};
```

The problem appears when I try to extract data from the container that is pointed by an ID:

```
bool PacketManager::AppendPacket(const Packet& pk)
{
    PacketQueue _queue;

    // The queue is passed by reference
    if (!l_ConnQueues.AtID(pk.ownerID, _queue))
        return false;

    // Append the packet
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> _l(_queue._mx);

    size_t InitSize = _queue.OutPackets.size();

    _queue.OutPackets.push(pk);

    // If data is not appended to the queue
    if (_queue.OutPackets.size() <= InitSize)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Debugging the function shows me that the data is appened to the temporary object from the queue, but not to the one from the container. I suspect the cause of this behaviour to be the ***copy constructor*** of the `PackeTQueue` class.

```
struct PacketQueue
{
    PacketQueue() { }

    uint32_t ID;
    std::mutex _mx;
    std::queue<Packet> OutPackets;

    PacketQueue& operator=(const PacketQueue& q)
    {
        ID = q.ID;
        OutPackets = q.OutPackets;
        return *this;
    }

    PacketQueue(const PacketQueue& queue)
    {
        ID = queue.ID;
        OutPackets = queue.OutPackets;
    }
};
```

My questions are:

- Why is this happening?
- What can I do to fix this error?
- Any suggestions on improving the design of the container class (`Query_List`)?

Comment: "_Why is this happening ?_" `To_Get = *m_IndexTable[ID];` Copies the value `m_IndexTable[ID]` to `To_Get`, and from this point onward, they are 2 disjoint instances of the same class.

Comment: And how I could make it point to the actual object from the container ?

Comment: @KolinVerdum Change the output parameter to a pointer instead of a reference. Or return a reference/pointer as a return value instead of using an output parameter

Comment: @KolinVerdum Either `return`ing a reference to one (in which you would lose the `return`ing of `true`/`false`), or via the use of pointers.

Comment: @KolinVerdum: and FYI, your `AtID()` and `Remove()` methods have a race condition. As soon as `Exists()` exits, another thread could come in and lock the mutex and alter the list/map before the current thread has a chance to re-lock the mutex. As such, they shouldn't be calling `Exists()` at all. And there is no need to check if `iterator == end` if the `ID` is found, if you manage your iterators correctly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I haven't noticed that ! Thank you, I will fix it !

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I will give that a try and come with an update !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `AtID()` method is returning a *copy* of the `PacketQueue` that is stored in `m_DataArray`.  If you want to access the original so that you can modify it, you need to change the `To_Get` output parameter to return a pointer:

```
bool AtID(uint32_t ID, Data* &To_Get)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(mx_lock);

    auto iter = m_IndexTable.find(ID);
    if (iter == m_IndexTable.end())
        return false;

    To_Get = &*(iter->second);
    return true;
}
```

```
bool PacketManager::AppendPacket(const Packet& pk)
{
    PacketQueue *queue;
    if (!l_ConnQueues.AtID(pk.ownerID, queue))
        return false;

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(queue->_mx);

    size_t InitSize = queue->OutPackets.size();
    queue->OutPackets.push(pk);
    return (queue->OutPackets.size() > InitSize);
}
```

Or, you can change `AtID()` to return the pointer as its return value instead of using an output parameter at all:

```
Data* AtID(uint32_t ID)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(mx_lock);

    auto iter = m_IndexTable.find(ID);
    if (iter == m_IndexTable.end())
        return nullptr;

    return &*(iter->second);
}
```

```
bool PacketManager::AppendPacket(const Packet& pk)
{
    PacketQueue *queue = l_ConnQueues.AtID(pk.ownerID);
    if (!queue)
        return false;

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(queue->_mx);
    queue->OutPackets.push(pk);

    return true;
}
```

Of course, that being said, since `l_ConnQueues`'s mutex is unlocked after `AtID()` exits, any other thread could *potentially* `Remove()` the `PacketQueue` from the list while `AppendPacket()` is still trying to push a packet into it.  So, it would be safer to have `AppendPacket()` keep the list's mutex locked until it is done updating the returned queue:

```
Data* AtID_NoLock(uint32_t ID)
{
    auto iter = m_IndexTable.find(ID);
    if (iter == m_IndexTable.end())
        return nullptr;

    return &*(iter->second);
}

Data* AtID(uint32_t ID)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(mx_lock);
    return AtID_NoLock(ID);
}

bool PacketManager::AppendPacket(const Packet& pk)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(l_ConnQueues.mx_lock);

    PacketQueue *queue = l_ConnQueues.AtID_NoLock(pk.ownerID);
    if (!queue)
        return false;

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l2(queue->_mx);
    queue->OutPackets.push(pk);

    return true;
}
```

---

That being said, you will notice that I changed `AtID()` to not use `Exists()` anymore.  There is a race condition (in `Remove()`, too) that, as soon as `Exists()` exits, another thread could come in and lock the mutex and alter the `list`/`map` before the current thread has a chance to re-lock the mutex. As such, `AtID()` (and `Remove()`) should not be calling `Exists()` at all.

Also, I don't suggest having `Remove()` set a stored `std:list` iterator to `end`, that just makes more work for `AtID()`.  It would be better to simply `erase` the found `ID` from the `map` altogether:

```
void Remove(uint32_t ID)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(mx_lock);

    auto iter = m_IndexTable.find(ID);
    if (iter != m_IndexTable.end())
    {
        m_DataArray.erase(iter->second);
        m_IndexTable.erase(iter);
    }
}
```

---

**Update**: That being said, there is really no good reason to have a `std::map` of `std::list` iterators at all. You can store your `PacketQueue` objects directly in the `std::map` and remove the `std::list` altogether:

```
template <typename Data>
class query_list {
private:
    std::mutex mx_lock;
    std::map<uint32_t, Data> m_Data;

public:
    query_list() { }

    void Push_Back(uint32_t ID, const Data& Val) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(mx_lock);
        // Add data to the container
        m_Data[ID] = Val;
    }

    Data* AtID_NoLock(uint32_t ID) {
        auto iter = m_Data.find(ID);
        return (iter != m_Data.end()) ? &(iter->second) : nullptr;
    }

    Data* AtID(uint32_t ID) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(mx_lock);
        return AtID_NoLock(ID);
    }

    void Remove(uint32_t ID) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(mx_lock);
        auto iter = m_Data.find(ID);
        if (iter != m_Data.end())
            m_Data.erase(iter);
    }

    bool Exists(uint32_t ID) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(mx_lock);
        return (m_Data.find(ID) != m_Data.end());
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the complete answare ! I initally thought that it might be good to cache the ID in the map so that I will get a better performance. Now that I'm thinking, if the program is under heavy load, it won't make such a big difference. Your solution is much more simpler.

Comment: @KolinVerdum the simpler solution would be to eliminate the `std::list` altogether and store the `PacketQueue` objects directly in the `std::map`. I updated my answer to show that.